# Join arguments to a zsh function with a separator and then pass those as arguments to a command

Tags: arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, zsh

Suppose I have a zsh function that is invoked as follows:

```
myFunction arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

What I would essentially like `myFunction()` to do is the following:

```
myFunction () {
  some-program prefix:arg1 or prefix:arg2 or prefix:arg3 ...
}
```

This is how I tried to do it:

```
myFunction () {
  local args="prefix:${1}"
  shift
  for arg; do
    args+=" or prefix:${arg}"
  done

  some-program $args
}
```

When I call this function, `some-program` doesn't work as expected, and my understanding is that it's because it is interpreting `$args` as a single argument instead of many separate arguments. How can I make the string given by `$args` be interpreted as several separate arguments?

Comment: I've found I can get my code to work as desired by having `args` be an array instead of a string. My shell scripting is not very strong, so although intuitively I can see why an array might work here, I'm still uncertain about how and when a string might be used in this circumstance. For example, I have another function which does `some-program prefix:${*}`, and this seems to work fine. My understanding was that `$*` resolves as a string, but perhaps that's not the case? If so, that may be part of the reason for my confusion.

Comment: `zsh` blurs the lines between parameters and arrays a little bit. In POSIX shell, `$*` is *just* a string; the string just happens to consist of all the positional parameters joined by a space (by default, but let's not get into that.) In `bash`, there *are* arrays, but `$*` is still just a single string; `${*[1]}` is an error. In `zsh`, you can treat `$*` as if it were an array to some extent (`${*[1]}` works, for example), but it is still primarily a string. There *is* an option you can set, `rc_expand_param`, which causes `prefix:$*` to expand to `prefix:$1 prefix:$2`, etc.